# How to create a Wave Animation in my shimmer control in WinUI-3 C#?

Tags: xaml, uwp, uwp-xaml, winui-3, winui

In WinUI-3 ,I have created Shimmer control structure for using ellipse and rectangle.

```
 <Style x:Key="ShimmerStyle" TargetType="local:Shimmer" >
        <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Center"/>
        <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center"/>
        <Setter Property="Fill" Value="{ThemeResource ShimmerFillColor}"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="local:Shimmer">
                    <StackPanel>
                        <Grid x:Name="Grid1">
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                            </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                            <Ellipse x:Name="Eli" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Height="200" Width="200" Fill="{TemplateBinding Fill}" HorizontalAlignment="Left">
                            </Ellipse>
                            <Rectangle x:Name="Rect" Margin="40,30,50,100" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Height="60" Width="800"  Fill="{TemplateBinding Fill}" Opacity="0.8" />
                            <Rectangle x:Name="Rect1" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Margin="40,90,0,0" Height="60" Width="300" Fill="{TemplateBinding Fill}"  HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
                        </Grid>
                        <Grid x:Name="Grid2" >
                            <ContentControl >
                                <ContentPresenter Content="{TemplateBinding Content}"/>
                            </ContentControl>
                        </Grid>
                    </StackPanel>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value> 
        </Setter>
    </Style>
   <Style BasedOn="{StaticResource ShimmerStyle}" TargetType="local:Shimmer"/>
```

In my Shimmer class i have created WaveColor and WaveDirection and AnimationDuration property.I have implemented the Fill,IsActive and Content property.
When the IsActive property is true. In my shimmer control are displayed.
When the IsActive property is false.my shimmer control are hided and It displayed the content property.

How do I create a Wave Animation for my Shimmer control in WinUI-3?. please help me

I tried to animation code in the XAML side with Storyboard using VisualStateGroup. But I couldn't create it.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

> How to create a Wave Animation in my shimmer control in WinUI-3 C#?

You have many ways to implement such animation, the first sample way is that do animation for `LinearGradientBrush` GradientStop `Offset` and `Color` property by using [`ColorAnimation`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.media.animation.coloranimation?view=winrt-22621) and [`DoubleAnimation`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.media.animation.doubleanimation?view=winrt-22621)

**Usage**

```
<Grid x:Name="LogoGrid">
    <Grid.Resources>
        <Storyboard x:Name="LoadingStoryBoard">
            <ColorAnimation
                EnableDependentAnimation="True"
                RepeatBehavior="Forever"
                Storyboard.TargetName="LogoGrid"
                Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Background).(LinearGradientBrush.GradientStops)[0].(GradientStop.Color)"
                From="Transparent"
                To="RosyBrown"
                Duration="0:0:2" />
            <DoubleAnimation
                EnableDependentAnimation="True"
                RepeatBehavior="Forever"
                Storyboard.TargetName="LogoGrid"
                Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Background).(LinearGradientBrush.GradientStops)[1].(GradientStop.Offset)"
                From="0"
                To="1"
                Duration="0:0:2" />
            <ColorAnimation
                EnableDependentAnimation="True"
                RepeatBehavior="Forever"
                Storyboard.TargetName="LogoGrid"
                Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Background).(LinearGradientBrush.GradientStops)[2].(GradientStop.Color)"
                From="RosyBrown"
                To="Transparent"
                Duration="0:0:2" />
        </Storyboard>
    </Grid.Resources>
    <Grid.Background>
        <LinearGradientBrush x:Name="LogoBackgroundBrush" StartPoint="0,0" EndPoint="1,1">
            <GradientStop x:Name="Stop0" Offset="0" Color="Transparent" />
            <GradientStop x:Name="Stop1" Offset="0.5" Color="RosyBrown" />
            <GradientStop x:Name="Stop2" Offset="1" Color="RosyBrown" />
        </LinearGradientBrush>
    </Grid.Background>
</Grid>
```

**Code Behind**

```
 public MainPage()
 {
     this.InitializeComponent();
     Loaded += (sender, args) => LoadingStoryBoard.Begin();
 }
```

And the second complete way is [Using lights in Windows UI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/composition/composition-lighting), you could refer the [official code sample](https://github.com/microsoft/WindowsCompositionSamples/tree/master/SampleGallery/Samples/SDK%2014393/TextShimmer) to make your own light animation.

Comment: I need animation for my 1st Grid Ellipse and Rectangle.Don't need entire grid. How to create an animation so that the wave is visible only in the ellipse and rectangle areas without taking the entire grid. in this wave direction is left to right.                                              any solution in WinUI-3?

Comment: please apply  above `LinearGradientBrush` to your want animated control just like code above

Comment: Any updates for this case ?